# Seaborn Heatmap Error: " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape' "

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

I am doing an NLP project looking at the cosine similarities between the respective works of 10 different classic rock artists. I have done similarity queries and created a dataframe called `similarities` that looks like this.

[image]

I built the `similarities` dataframe by first building an empty one with the artist names as the indices and the column names and then ran the following code to run the similarity queries and populate the dataframe with the scores:

```
        
    artist_words = data['lyrics'][artist]
    
    artist_vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(artist_words.lower().split())
    artist_vec_lsi = lsi[artist_vec_bow]
    
    artist_sims = index[artist_vec_lsi]
    
    artist_sims_sorted = sorted(enumerate(artist_sims), key=lambda item: -item[1])
    
    for position, score in artist_sims_sorted:
    
        similarities.at[artist, musicians[position][1]] = score
```

`data` is a dataframe with the artist names as the indices and a column called `lyrics` in which the lyrics are entered as one long string.

I would like to create a Seaborn heatmap to visualize the correlations indicated in the DataFrame.

But when I run the following code:

`sns.heatmap(similarities)`

I get a long error message that concludes with :

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

*Can anyone help me figure out how to visualize this?*

`similarities.info()` returns the following:

```
Index: 11 entries, bob_dylan to willie_nelson
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   bob_dylan       11 non-null     object
 1   david_bowie     11 non-null     object
 2   janis_joplin    11 non-null     object
 3   john_prine      11 non-null     object
 4   leonard_cohen   11 non-null     object
 5   linda_ronstadt  11 non-null     object
 6   mark_knopfler   11 non-null     object
 7   neil_young      11 non-null     object
 8   stevie_nicks    11 non-null     object
 9   the_band        11 non-null     object
 10  willie_nelson   11 non-null     object
dtypes: object(11)
memory usage: 1.3+ KB
```

`similarities.describe()` returns the following:

[similarities.describe()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q34gK.png)

In case the full error message is helpful, here it is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/tb/j430qmhn16s6nsz08nf0y7y40000gn/T/ipykernel_40566/1345125298.py in <module>
----> 1 ax2 = sns.heatmap(
      2     similarities,
      3     vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,
      4     cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=200),
      5     square=True

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, ax, **kwargs)
    546     if square:
    547         ax.set_aspect("equal")
--> 548     plotter.plot(ax, cbar_ax, kwargs)
    549     return ax
    550 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py in plot(self, ax, cax, kws)
    330         # Possibly rotate them if they overlap
    331         if hasattr(ax.figure.canvas, "get_renderer"):
--> 332             ax.figure.draw(ax.figure.canvas.get_renderer())
    333         if axis_ticklabels_overlap(xtl):
    334             plt.setp(xtl, rotation="vertical")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     72     @wraps(draw)
     73     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 74         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     75         if renderer._rasterizing:
     76             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2778 
   2779             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 2780             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   2781                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   2782 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    429                          else deprecation_addendum,
    430                 **kwargs)
--> 431         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    432 
    433     return wrapper

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2919             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2920 
-> 2921         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2922 
   2923         renderer.close_group('axes')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2099                 offsets = np.column_stack([xs, ys])
   2100 
-> 2101         self.update_scalarmappable()
   2102 
   2103         if not transform.is_affine:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in update_scalarmappable(self)
    924                 # pcolormesh, scatter, maybe others flatten their _A
    925                 self._alpha = self._alpha.reshape(self._A.shape)
--> 926             self._mapped_colors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)
    927 
    928         if self._face_is_mapped:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py in to_rgba(self, x, alpha, bytes, norm)
    358         if norm:
    359             x = self.norm(x)
--> 360         rgba = self.cmap(x, alpha=alpha, bytes=bytes)
    361         return rgba
    362 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in __call__(self, X, alpha, bytes)
    612             self._init()
    613 
--> 614         mask_bad = X.mask if np.ma.is_masked(X) else np.isnan(X)  # Mask nan's.
    615         xa = np.array(X, copy=True)
    616         if not xa.dtype.isnative:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    248 
    249     if 'png' in formats:
--> 250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    251     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    252         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    132         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    133 
--> 134     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    135     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    136     if fmt == 'svg':

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2228                        else suppress())
   2229                 with ctx:
-> 2230                     self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2231 
   2232             if bbox_inches:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     72     @wraps(draw)
     73     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 74         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     75         if renderer._rasterizing:
     76             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2778 
   2779             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 2780             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   2781                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   2782 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    429                          else deprecation_addendum,
    430                 **kwargs)
--> 431         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    432 
    433     return wrapper

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2919             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2920 
-> 2921         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2922 
   2923         renderer.close_group('axes')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     49                 renderer.start_filter()
     50 
---> 51             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     52         finally:
     53             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2128                 coordinates, offsets, transOffset,
   2129                 # Backends expect flattened rgba arrays (n*m, 4) for fc and ec
-> 2130                 self.get_facecolor().reshape((-1, 4)),
   2131                 self._antialiased, self.get_edgecolors().reshape((-1, 4)))
   2132         gc.restore()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'
<Figure size 432x288 with 2 Axes>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   There could be an issue with the ```similarites``` value.

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can only tell you what is wrong with code that we can actually see; and since the `.heatmap` method is supposed to be usable for something, presumably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Which version of seaborn are you running?  Could you add  (as text) the output of `similarities.info()` and `similarities.describe()`?  Are you sure `similarities` isn't an empty dataframe?

Comment: Any chance you could put in the data rather than a screenshot of it? A 6x6 would be fine.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you! I've added a bunch more code that might help.

Comment: @JohanC `similarities` is definitely not empty. Sorry about the confusion! I just added both `.info()` and `.describe()` to the question. (They both got messed up as text so .info() had to be in a code block and .describe() is an image, sorry.) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @hrokr I added code to explain how I created the `similarities` dataframe. I hope that helps. Not sure how to put in data as 6x6, i'm very sorry.

Comment: `dtype` being `object` means your values are pure numbers. Maybe there are some strings in between? Maybe `similarities.at[artist, musicians[position][1]] = float(score)` could work?

Comment: @JohanC you found the issue! Your code didn't work, but running `similarities = similarities.apply(pd.to_numeric)` changed all columns to `float64` and I was then able to successfully render a heatmap for the `similarities` dataframe. Thank you so much, everyone!

Answer (score 6):

This is because of the type used, I just had this problem and solved it by specifying a dtype for my dataframe. In your similarities.info() seaborn wants to see DType:'float64' or another number type.

`similarities = pd.DataFrame(..., dtype="float")`